# Страд. причастие наст. времени от "слышать"

Tags: причастия, морфология

Есть ли у глагола *слышать* **страдательное** причастие **настоящего** времени? Я думаю это будет *слышимый*. Но [эта таблица](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) говорит, что такой формы нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такое причастие: слышать - слышит - слышимый.

"Давнишний глас на лире оживает, Чуть слышимый, как Гения полет, И душу хладную разогревает" (Н. Полевой).

Comment: О какой таблице речь? У Зализняка в парадигме глагола слышать есть слышимый.Может, от "услышать"?

Comment: Какая-то "левая" у Вас таблица, там  страдательного вообще нет, только краткое страдательное. Это откуда? Может, там не весь материал?